# Retrieving and Sending JSON data using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: json, xml

I am learning about using XMLHttpRequest to recieve JSON data from an api and also to post data, I have the following code to GET the JSON data,

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        json;

```
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'URL', true);
xmlhttp.send();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        console.log(json);
        var string = JSON.stringify(json);
        console.log(string);
    }
};
```

However I am struggling to work out how to POST the data back to an api, after I have stringified a JSON object is this how I POST it?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'URL', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
xhr.send(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'URL');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(myData));
```