# Having trouble parsing json file in my javascript..but I am getting "responseObject.weather[i].weatherresponseObject.weather[i].description"

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Trying to parse data from a php file which is in json format to an html file using javascript to do so
I am getting responseObject.weather[i].weatherresponseObject.weather[i].description but I have a hunch its how the php file is formatted and perhaps the object I am using is not correct
I am trying to just pull the temperature and the description onto my html page.
Can someone give me a idea of where it is going wrong?

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="run.js"></script>
  <title>Ajax Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="title">Todays Weather Forecast</h1>
  <p class="sub">Click the button the check the local weather.</p>

  <button class="demo-centered" type="button" onclick="loadPhp()">Check Weather</button><br><br>
  <div id="content"></p>
</body>

</html>

function loadPhp() {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    responseObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    var newContent = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < responseObject.weather.length; i++){
      newContent += 'responseObject.weather[i].weather';
      newContent += 'responseObject.weather[i].description';


    }
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = newContent;
  }
};

xhr.open('GET', 'demo.php', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

}

```
{"coord":{"lon":-116.8,"lat":33.03},"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":293.73,"feels_like":289.89,"temp_min":289.26,"temp_max":295.93,"pressure":1016,"humidity":52},"visibility":16093,"wind":{"speed":5.7,"deg":260},"clouds":{"all":40},"dt":1589408840,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5686,"country":"US","sunrise":1589374130,"sunset":1589423903},"timezone":-25200,"id":5391832,"name":"San Diego County","cod":200}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving and Sending JSON data using XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132340/retrieving-and-sending-json-data-using-xmlhttprequest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the quotes in this code:

```
newContent += 'responseObject.weather[i].weather';
newContent += 'responseObject.weather[i].description';
```

With the quotes, you're making those literal strings. Instead:

```
newContent += responseObject.weather[i].weather;
newContent += responseObject.weather[i].description;
```

...though you probably want some markup around those, as they'll just be stuck together.

---

Three other things worth noting:

1. You never do anything with `newContent`. You need to do something to put it on the page (append elements with it, append it to existing elements, etc.).
2. Your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) — you need to declare `responseObject`.
3. It's fine to use `XMLHttpRequest`, but you might also look at the newer [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) instead. If you do, though, beware the [`fetch` footgun](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).